# Mass rename in linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed, rename

Can you please tell how to use rename to rename all the files , leaving the first 8 characters and extension , for example :

I have:

```
001 -superfile-blaha_bla.txt
```

I need:

```
001 -sup.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rename 's/^(.{8}).*/$1/' *
```

would truncate files to 8 characters or fewer. If truncation causes two or more files to get mapped to the same name, `rename` would by default issue a warning and refuse to overwrite all but one of the files involved in the name conflict.

If you use

```
rename --force 's/^(.{8}).*/$1/' *
```

then `rename` will overwrite the files.

Comment: Sorry, but my rename utility hasnt options --force   $ rename --version
rename from util-linux 2.27

Comment: According to this [util-linux rename man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), "The renaming has no safeguards." So it appears with util-linux, the behavior I described for `--force` is the default with util-linux's `rename`.

Comment: <pre lang="bash"><code>[int13h@homepc test]$ ls -1
111asdfasdfMjflksdf.txt
asdfasdfMjflksdf.txt
fsdafs111asdfasdfMjflksdf.txt
gggfsdafs111asdfasdfMjflksdf.txt
Myjakfjkldjflksdf.txt
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.txt
[int13h@homepc test]$ rename 's/^(.{8}).*/$1/' *
[int13h@homepc test]$ ls -1
111asdfasdfMjflksdf.txt
asdfasdfMjflksdf.txt
fsdafs111asdfasdfMjflksdf.txt
gggfsdafs111asdfasdfMjflksdf.txt
Myjakfjkldjflksdf.txt
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.txt
[int13h@homepc test]$</code></pre>

Comment: rename 's/^(.{8}).*/$1/' *               Dont work in my distro

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=$'\n'
files=`ls -1 $1`
for x in $files
do
    filename="$x"
    if [ $filename = `basename $0` ] # do not include this script file
        then
        echo "skipping script file"
        continue 
    fi
    suffix=${filename: -4}
    name=${filename:0:8}
    echo "renaming $x to $name$suffix" 
    mv $1/"$x" $1/$name$suffix
done
```

Usage: script directory_name

Caveats:
Will overwrite duplicates, file names shorter than 8 chars will end up with a partial double suffix i.e. ab.dat would end up being ab.dat.dat